# Colored text not printing correctly in Python (Win 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to print text colored to my Terminal output, but all I get is some  broken text. What I get: `?[3;34;40mtest?[0m`

and here's the code: 
`print('\x1b[3;34;40m' + 'test' + '\x1b[0m')`

I get the same error when trying with  the Colorama module, too.

Comment: Try using raw string notation in string `rf"\x1b[3;34;40m{test}\x1b[0m"`. Where the test is a variable.

Comment: @Vishnudev I don't know if I did it correctly, but here's what I got: `\x1b[3;34;40masdsdgf\x1b[0m`

Comment: Why not simply use the [termcolor module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor)?

Comment: Because I still get the same text output....

Comment: I think your terminal is different from usual ones, because its working in mine.

Comment: It's weird how I made a script that uses colors before and it still works, and now, even if I copy + paste it, it won't work.

Comment: Exactly. Something is wrong with your terminal. Try running `bash` in your terminal and then execute.